# Gradle - How to execute something after a copy task completed the operation?

Tags: gradle

I have a task:

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from 'from.txt'
    into 'into.txt'
    doLast {
        //Read write 'into.txt'
    }
}
```

It always print a `FileNotFoundException`, I find out that `doLast` block is executed before the copy operation has complete, so how can I read (or write) with `into.file` when my copy operation is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are not using Copy task in a proper way:  the "into" property is the target directory where files will be copied, not the target file name. 
When executing your script you should have a directory "input.txt" created at the root directory of your project, and the file "from.txt" copied into it , which is not what you expect, and I guess this is the cause for you *FileNotFoundException* .

If you want to copy/rename file, you should use the 'rename' method from CopyTask, described here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Exemple:

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from './source-file.txt'
    into './output-dir'
    rename ( 'source-file.txt', 'input.txt')
    doLast{
        println "Is file already copied when executing doLast ? ==>  "+   project.file("./output-dir/input.txt").exists()
    }
}
```

This should output:

```
$ gradle myCopy
> Task :myCopy
Is file already copied when executing doLast ? ==>  true
```